# Google Sheets: Count number of rows in a column that do not match corresponding row in another column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif, sumproduct

Say we have the following spreadsheet in google sheets:

```
a  a
b  b
c  
d  e
e  d
```

How would I build a formula that counts the number of rows in column B that do not match the corresponding row in column A, and are not blank? In other words I want to get the number of rows that changed to a new letter in column B. So in this example the formula should return 2.

Thank you for your help.

UPDATE:

Now suppose I have this spreadsheet:

```
a  a  
b  b  b
c     a
d  e  e
e  d  e
```

How would I build on the last formula for the third column, where the value returned is:

- (the number of rows in column 3 that don't match the corresponding row in column 2) + (if column 2 is blank, the number of rows in column 3 that do not match the corresponding row in column 1)
- and I also don't want to count blanks in the third column.

The value returned in this case should be 2 (rows 3 and 5).

Comment: Changing the question after people have answered may invalidate answers. I'd advise that you ask a follow on question, and link this question there instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me it sounds like you could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B:B<>"")*(B:B<>A:A))
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great. I updated the post asking about a slightly more complicated formula for a third column, if you are interested and are able to take a look at it.

Comment: I don't understand the first requirement @gus_mac.

Comment: updated for clarity. The first requirement is the same as my previous question which can be answered with the formula you provided.

Comment: I guess you would miss the requirement that B:B can't be empty in that case. Maybe try `=SUMPRODUCT((B:B<>"")*(C:C<>B:B)*(C:C<>""))+SUMPRODUCT((B:B="")*(A:A<>C:C)*(C:C<>""))` @gus_mac

Answer (score 4):

```
=IFNA(ROWS(FILTER(A:B,
  (A:A<>B:B)*
  (B:B<>"")
)),0)
```

1. `FILTER` by matching conditions `*` for AND `+` for OR.
2. `ROWS` counts rows
3. `IFNA` returns 0 if nothing was found.

or with `QUERY`

```
=INDEX(QUERY(A:B,"select count(B) where B<>A"),2)
```

Comment: I like this solution much better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64032709/4294399  Go upvote that one.

Comment: Will do. I updated the post to inquire about a formula for a third column that would be slightly more complicated, if you are interested and able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA($B$1:$B)-SUM(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A, $B$1:$B,$B$1:$B,"<>")))
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks Marios, I actually made a mistake in asking my question though. I updated the example to reflect what I'm looking for. In the new example, your formula returns "0" instead of 2, I think because it is comparing comparing all values in one column to all values in the other, instead of just comparing one cell to the one next to it. I believe calculuswhiz's solution works for what im looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 ways to complete this.

First you could add a function to each row to return 1 or 0 if the value changed and was not blank and then sum results. This unfortunately adds a messy column in your spreadsheet.

```
=if(A1<>IF(ISBLANK(B1),A1,B1),1,0)
```

Second you could create a function where you would pass the range as a string.
The call from the worksheet would look like this:

```
=myFunction("A1:B5")
```

Then create a script by opening Tools -> Script editor and use something like this

```
function myFunction(r) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(r);
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var areDifferent = 0;
  
  for (let i=1; i<= numRows; i++) {
    let currentValue = range.getCell(i,1).getValue();
    let cmpValue = range.getCell(i,2).getValue();
    if ((currentValue != cmpValue) && (cmpValue != "")) {
      areDifferent++;
    }
  }
  return areDifferent;
}
```